# Xcode 10 autocomplete not working in other swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10

**Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255)**

I have a struct in MyStruct.swift

```
struct MyStruct {
  var aa = ""
  var bb = ""
}
```

In MyStruct.swift autocomplete it's working.

[image]

In other file it's not working.

[image]

I try deleting derivedData, it's not working too :(

Comment: Make sure that both files have the same target selected.

Comment: Clean project / Clean derived data  / restart xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is some issue with the auto-suggestion in Xcode-10. I just tried with the below example and found that suggestion were not appearing for default initialisation. However if you write and compile, it will work.

```
let newObj = MyStruct(aa: "1", bb: "2")
```

Even if you want to debug it more, use `init` method, it will show auto-suggestion as well:

```
let newObj1 = MyStruct.init(aa: "A", bb: "B")
```

**`MyStruct.swift`**

```
import Foundation

struct MyStruct {
    var aa = ""
    var bb = ""
}

func test() {
    let myStruct = MyStruct(aa: "", bb: "")
    print(myStruct)
}
```

**`ViewController.swift`**

```
import UIKit

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let newObj = MyStruct(aa: "1", bb: "2")
    print(newObj)

    let newObj1 = MyStruct.init(aa: "A", bb: "B")
    print(newObj1)
}
```